# Bootstrap Menu issue with Scrollspy

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to recreate the GetBootstrap site menu using ScrollSpy.  My Bootply started from PzDaCtkigV bootply (Found [Here](http://www.bootply.com/95998)), and I'm extending it further to match GetBootstrap's menu.  The problem I'm having is that when you scroll down to Section 3, it has 2 sub-items.  As you scroll, the highlighting works, but on a sub-item, it doesn't highlight the same as the main item.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the highlighting to match the main items...

Example of issue: http://www.bootply.com/jUOt0tc9nW

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to reduce the spacing between menu items.

Comment: Ok, adding the 'nav' class to each list item, corrected the problem with the vertical bar.  Now i'm just trying to change the spacing of the list items

Comment: You can adjust the padding (ie:`.nav >li>a{padding:4px;}`)

Comment: That fixed my spacing issue.  The bootply sample is now updated with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jUOt0tc9nW) to reflect the solution.  In the future, I'm going to try to get the sub-menu vertical lines to not be indented.  But the solution is really close, so I'm going to implement it in my project and come back later for the vertical lines.

NOTE:  I had a problem when on sm and xm devices the menu would be on top of the content.  If you have this problem, use hidden-xs and hidden-sm to hide the menu

Comment: I found an issue with submenus.  If you have more than one submenu, the jquery will open up all submenus at once.  I've updated in the Bootply, adding $('.submenu li').addClass('hide').  It night not be the best solution, but it works.